# How to use user defined variable in Jmeter as server name or Ip while writing scripts using Transaction controller and Test script controller

Tags: jmeter

When I am using the Jmeter while recording the script, I want to use a user-defined variable which is the website address. When an HTTP request is created by the Test script recorder, the Server name or IP is created automatically, but what I want is to set those server names manually using a variable.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're recording your test, but when you create the recording test plan from the [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) it asks you for the protocol and  hostname and populates them in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so you basically have server name in one place only and in the HTTP Request samplers it can be empty.

If you want to have it as a variable you can define one in the [User Defined Variales](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configuration element and replace the value in the HTTP Request Defaults with the JMeter Variable reference.

[image]